# Best way of storing data in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I just started developing a Google web app, may I know what is the best way of storing data? Is it by using scriptDB, spreadsheets or JDBC?

Comment: Warning: ScriptDB was deprecated on May 15, 2014, and will be turned off on November 20, 2014. To move your data to a different type of database, see the guide to migrating from ScriptDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the hard work out of working with data storage by using this library:
http://www.harryonline.net/scripts/objdb-storing-data-with-google-apps-script/482

Using this library, you can work both with spreadsheets and JDBC databases, and easily switch if you later change your mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the data directly, then you can save data in spreadsheet and build apps based on spreadsheet data. If you store data in ScriptDB, you can not edit data easily. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, finally we worked with JDBC we Connected our app with a Cloud Database:Xeround and it's working great I can isert retrieve data from it and see the schema of tables! I'm not sure it's the best way but for me it is !